# Problems Installing Python igraph

Tags: python, installation, igraph

I installed the igraph python library using pip

```
sudo pip install python-igraph
```

I go on the Python console/terminal and import the module

```
$ python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Sep 26 2013, 03:20:26) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import igraph
```

No problem. Then I test to see the version number

```
>>> print igraph.__version__
0.6
```

No problem there either. But when I try to create a script.

```
from igraph import *
g = Graph()
```

And execute

```
python2.7 script.py
```

or

```
python script.py
```

All i get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 1, in <module>
    from igraph import *
  File ".../script.py", line 2, in <module>
    g = Graph()
NameError: name 'Graph' is not defined
```

Comment: Why are you running it with `python2.7` instead of just `python`?

Comment: Just to show that it is the same version.
But, if execut `Python script.py` shows the same error

Comment: After you do the import from the console. What is the result of typing `dir(igraph)`. That will return all the attributes of the module.

Comment: I removed completely python and IGRAPH and installed again. It worked. Thanks to all

Comment: I guess you had a directory called `igraph` in the current working directory, and `import` loaded that instead of the installed package.

Comment: I agree. However, I used only the pip command, but I did not configure anything. Do not really know what might have happened. But I'm curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, as your script:

```
import igraph
g = igraph.Graph(1)
```

Global imports are generally not encouraged.

Comment: this way occurs this error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Graph'`

Comment: Try putting `dir(igraph)` in your script and running that. Compare with the output from the terminal. See what attributes are available and which ones are missing.

Comment: I removed completely python and IGRAPH and installed again. It worked. Thanks to all

Answer (score 3):

There are *two different* igraph packages for python I saw. If you don't want to use igraph from [here](https://github.com/patrickfuller/igraph/), and want to the one from [here](http://igraph.org); then go to terminal and type

```sh
pip uninstall igraph
```

then

```sh
pip install python-igraph
```

done!